# Creating a database using JSON files

Tags: json, database, file, save

[image]

Hello, my question is simple but I don't know if it's possible to realize it.
I've got json files structured like that one in the picture and I'd like to use these files, (actually I'd like to use the information contained in them), to create a database. I wanted to understand if it's possible to do this, without the necessity of transcribing all information again, but simply by moving the files into the database that will automatically save them in it.

Comment: Yes, it's possible, but you will either have to use a database client designed to convert JSON to tables or design your own program to do the conversion.

Comment: For the future: please copy the text in your image in code tags in your description.